# How to backup image files on MediaWiki 1.20.4 using dumpUploads.php

Tags: linux, mediawiki

I have run this same backup command on previous versions of MediaWiki (on Centos 6.4) and it has worked successfully but now when running this command on MediaWiki 1.20.4 -

```
[root@wiki images]# php /var/www/html/wiki/maintenance/dumpUploads.php --base=$(pwd) | xargs -I foo cp 'foo' . -v
```

I get the following errors -

```
cp: cannot stat `mwstore://local-backend/local-public/0/07/Xvidcap-test.swf': 
No such file or directory
```

I can see this is because the location does not exist but how can I get around this?

Comment: Would there be the possibility to download the images manually? What is the mwstore? If I run a locate for the image it is not found but it is in the wiki. The defulat location for images is   /var/www/html/wiki/images and there is a similar file structure   [root@wiki images]# ls
0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  a  archive  b  c  d  e  f  lockdir  README  thumb

Comment: Ok so my work around is this - find /var/www/html/wiki/images/ -type f -exec cp '{}' ./ \;

Comment: ugh, that can go wrong in quite many ways. Why don't you just `tar cf images.tar /var/www/html/wiki/images/`?

Answer (score 0):

[Manual:dumpUploads.php](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:DumpUploads.php) recommends tar, like `php maintenance/dumpUploads.php | xargs tar cf backup_files.tar`.

However, if your aim is **backup**, you should preserve the [directory structure you're using](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgHashedUploadDirectory). As [Manual:Backing up a wiki](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Special:MyLanguage/Manual:Backing_up_a_wiki) recommends, just use tar, e.g.:

```
tar caf images.tar.gz /var/www/html/wiki/images/
```

if you want to backup the uploads only and to compress them a bit.

Note, mwstore is the [file backend](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FileBackend.php).

Comment: That hasn’t worked for at least a couple versions, not even at the time you posted it.   You cannot directly tar output like `mwstore://local-backend/local-public/example_2.png`.

Comment: @TechZilla I'd call that a bug, but the first line is only an introduction to the matter. My proposed solution is the second command, did you try that?